# Does the MongoDB Inc.'s async driver (java) multiplex requests over a connection?

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous, mongodb-java

I've been trying to get some clarity on the way the [sync](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/) and [async](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver-async/) drivers by Mongo DB Inc. differ in terms of underlying implementation, but seem to not find any information on it. Specifically, I'm interested in knowing if, with the async driver, we get the advantage of requests being multiplexed over a single connection. If so, what is the limits for the number of concurrent requests for a connection pool with n connections?

On the ticket here - https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/issues/1039 , the comment by @allanbank says that multiplexing is implemented for the async driver, but it's not clear if it's referring to the [MongoDB Inc's driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver-async/) or [allanbank's driver](http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/index.html).